# How is a date compared to a number in the SQL standard

Tags: mysql, sql

Does the following have predictable behavior, or is this not defined and up to how the database implements it?

```
select date '2015-01-02' > 2015;
-- or --
select '2015-01-02' > 2015;
```

In other words, comparing a date (or string that can be cast to a date) to an integer that is a year.

Comment: In the SQL standard this wouldn't be allowed and results in an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are quite different, because the first compares a date to a number and the second compares a string to a number.

In standard SQL, both would return an error, but the errors would be slightly different.  In the first, the error would be something like "date cannot be converted to int".  In the second, it would be something like "string cannot be converted to int".  Most databases follow the type conversion rules of the standard.

MySQL does very strange things.  It will convert a date to a number format of the form YYYYMMDD.  So the first expression returns false and the second true:

```
select date '2015-01-01' = 2015, date '2015-01-01' = 20150101
```

See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2dc80df94e14ad9a0ccdcb18688556d).

I would strongly discourage you from depending on this behavior.

In the realm of strings, this returns true:

```
select '2015-01-01' = 2015
```

However, what looks like a similar example returns false:

```
select '2015.01.01' = 2015
```

This is because MySQL converts leading characters to a number, until it no longer can.

I would advise you to avoid even thinking about such constructs and not depending on the results of implicit conversion (explicit conversion is a different matter).  The following are the best way to determine if a date falls in a particular year:

```
where year(date) = 2015
where date >= '2015-01-01' and date < '2016-01-01'
```

Comment: thanks, why is this ok? `where date >= '2015-01-01' and date < '2016-01-01'` I thought you mentioned it's not a good idea to compare to a string, so wouldn't that need to be `where date >=(date '2015-01-01') and date < (date '2016-01-01')` ?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 . . . In the example in your comment, you are comparing a date to a *string* not a number.  Further, the string is in the standard format for a date.  So, the string constant is readily converted into a date.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally completely up to the database.  However, here is a correct way to express your inequalities:

```sql
select date '2015-01-02' >= date '2015-01-01' AND
       date '2015-01-02' <  date '2016-01-01'
```

The above inequality checks if the `'2015-01-02'` date occur anywhere in the 2015 calendar year.  It is also ANSI compliant, and should work on most SQL databases (though note that not all SQL databases require/use the `date` keyword when defining date literals).

Comment: It is not really up to the database, except in the sense that databases can choose to follow the standard or not.  The standard is pretty explicit about what happens in these cases (well, insofar as the SQL standard can be unambiguous about anything).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why do you feel the need to answer every question?

Answer (score 1):

The only databases (I know of) that would accept as valid expressions like:

```
date '2015-01-02' > 2015
```

and

```
'2015-01-02' > 2015
```

are MySql and MariaDB because they do implicit [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html).
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=01596c4272a8646b27288dfe8f5f9c92).

SQLite would also accept the 2nd expression for the same reason, but not the 1st query because it does not use the keyword `date` to cast a string to date.

Databases like SQL Server, Oracle or Postgresql need explicit data type conversions (if possible) so that the 2 operands can be compared.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a24aaa9bba265b4601b016ea9910b22

Comment: @Akina right, as I said Mysql does implicit conversions.

Comment: No, I mean that without `date` keyword the implicit convertion is clear, whereas with the presence of it the results interpretation is more difficult.

Comment: @Akina from the documentation link in my answer: "If one of the arguments is a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column and the other argument is a constant, the constant is converted to a timestamp before the comparison is performed." So in this case a constant like 2014 is converted to date, but which date?

Comment: TIMESTAMP or DATETIME - but not DATE.

Comment: @Akina Since the rules do not explicitly mention DATE I assume that the same rule for DATETIME applies for DATE.

Comment: No-no... DATE differs from DATETIME/TIMESTAMP - see, for example, autoutilizing or default value. In the first block of a fiddle numeric context is used, and `date '2015-01-02'` is converted to integer 20150102 which then is used in compare.

Comment: And it is better to refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html - for example, it is not obvious that `timestamp '2015-01-02'` will produce an error.

Comment: @Akina correct, this is the last rule: "In **all other cases**, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers."